# What type of numbers are roots of polynomial which is not solvable by radicals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, galois-theory

I studied Galois Theory and then Abel–Ruffini theorem which states that polynomials of degree 5 and above are in general not solvable by radicals.
Then what we call to roots of polynomial which is unsolvable ?
Obviously, we can't call them transcendental, as it will be against its definition.
So, what type of numbers are they? Are they having some special properties?

Comment: The special property is that they are defined as being the root of some complicated polynomial instead of having an expression with nested n-th roots. The radical numbers form a subfield of the algebraic numbers. What do you expect more ?

Comment: We call them "algebraic numbers" (assuming these are nonzero polynomials with integer coefficients), regardless of whether they can be expressed in terms of radicals.

Comment: @MPW I know it. But, when I searched for roots in exact form of $x^5-x-1$ on Wolfram alpha then it showed it in some weird form. And it is written that it is expressed in generalized hypergeometric function.